# Calcular quantiles en base a grupos para luego categorizar observaciones

Tags: r

Dado un dataset con una variable y numerica, 2 factores A y B. Necesito calcular los quantiles 0, 0,33, 0,66 y 1 para cada factor. Para luego convertir la variable y en base a los cuantiles de A y B.

Utilicé el siguiente codigo para calcular los quantiles.

`aggregate(data$y ~ data$factor, data, quantile, prob=c(0.0,0.33,0.66,1))`

Luego quisera en mi dataframe para A y B clasificar el valor de y en base a categorias (0-0.33 bajo, 0.33 a 0.66 medio y 0.66 a 1 alto). Pero que esa categorización dependa de lso cuantiles calculados para A y B diferencialmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo datos como estos

```
set.seed(2021)
data <- data.frame(factor = sample(c('A', 'B'), 10, replace = TRUE),
                   y = runif(10))
```

Usando R base puede resolverse de forma bastante simple:

```
categorizar <- function(y, probs=c(0.33,0.66), labels=c("Bajo","Medio","Alto")) {
  intervalos <- c(-Inf,quantile(y, probs=probs), Inf)
  labels[findInterval(y, intervalos)]
}

data <- data[order(data$factor),]
data$categoria <- unlist(lapply(split(data$y, data$factor), categorizar))
data

   factor          y categoria
1       A 0.02726706      Bajo
5       A 0.82005281      Alto
2       B 0.83749040      Alto
3       B 0.60324073     Medio
4       B 0.56745337     Medio
6       B 0.25157128      Bajo
7       B 0.50549403      Bajo
8       B 0.86753810      Alto
9       B 0.95818157      Alto
10      B 0.54569770      Bajo
```

Lo importante es tener el `data.frame` ordenado por `factor` para hacer más directo el proceso. La función `categorizar` simplemente hace coincidir las etiquetas `labels` según caigan en los cuantiles dados por `probs`, aprovechando la útil función [`findInterval()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/findInterval)

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

Debe haber varias formas de hacerlo, una es hacer una función que tome un vector numérico x, calcule los cuantiles deseados y luego según las categorias, cree otro vector que clasifique. El número de categorias debe ser uno más el numero de cuantiles.
Si los datos están clasificados por un factor, uno puede aplicar la función anterior con `lapply()`, el tema es que este devuelve una lista con un elemento por nivel del factor, habría que volver a reconstruir el data.frame. La tentación es dividir los datos en una lista con un elemento por nivel del factor con `split()` y usar un ciclo `for` para recorrerla, aplicar la claisificacion y luego pegar los elementos o unirlos. Pero a mi no me gusta usar ciclos `for`  ni `while` ni `repeat`.
Finalmente, uso `tapply` par aplicar la función clasificadora a los datos por cada nivel del factor, luego uso la instrucción `do.call(rbind.data.frame, mi_lista)` para convertir mi_lista en data.frame y luego lo reconstruyo al orden original haciendo un `match` del vector numerico con el original. Aquí podría haber problemas con datos numéricos duplicados que tengan asociado más de un nivel en el factor. Pero llegué hasta áca!

```
# genero datos artificiales
y <- rnorm(100, 10, 1)
f <- rep(c("A","B"), 50)
data <- data.frame(y,f)

clasificador <- function(x, cuantiles = c(1/3, 2/3), categ = c("bajo", "medio", "alto")) {
  # Validaciones -----------------------
  if (!is.numeric(cuantiles) | !all(cuantiles > 0) | !all(cuantiles <= 1)) {
    stop("Vector de cuantiles debe ser numerico y sus elementos estar entre 0 y 1")
  } 
  if (!is.data.frame(x) | !is.numeric(x[,1]) ) {
    stop("Error en los datos")
  }
  if (!is.factor(x[,2])) {
    x[,2] <- as.factor(x[,2])
  }
  # puedes agregar más validaciones
  # ------------------------------------

  # esta funcion clasifica un vector numerico en tres categorias
  # de acuerdo a los cuantiles
  clasificadorInterno <- function(x, cuant, categ) {
    zz <- rep("", length(x))
    qs <- quantile(x, probs = cuant)
    zz[x < qs[1]] <- categ[1]
    zz[(x >= qs[1]) & (x < qs[2])] <- categ[2]
    zz[x >= qs[2]] <- categ[3] 
    data.frame(x,zz)
  }

  # esta funcion aplica clasificadorInterno a los datos dividos por el factor
  clasif <- function(x) {
    tapply(x[,1], list(x[,2]), clasificadorInterno, cuantiles, categ)
  }
  # esto es para unir la lista en un dataframe
  zz <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, clasif(x))

  # y esto para devolverlo en el mismo orden que el ingresado
  clasificacion <- zz[match(x[,1], zz[,1]),2]
  cbind(x, clasificacion)
}

clasificador(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás familiarizado con `tidyverse/dplyr` puedes resolverlo de una forma muy clara y concisa:

```
library("tidyverse")

data %>% 
  left_join(data %>% 
              group_by(factor) %>% 
              do(data.frame(t(quantile(.$y, probs = c(0.33,0.66))))),
            by = "factor"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(categoria =  case_when(
                        y <= X33. ~ "Bajo", 
                        y > X33. & y <=  X66. ~ "Medio",
                        y >  X66. ~ "Alto"
                        )
         ) %>% 
  select(factor, y, categoria)
```

Básicamente "unimos" los cuantiles con tu `data.frame` original por cada `factor` mediante un `left_join()`, y luego simplemente generamos la variable `categoria` en función de la construcción lógica del `case_when()`